# IE9 - Quirks Mode in main page and "Internet Explorer 9 Standards" in specific iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode, x-ua-compatible

We have a legacy website which runs in all our clients on IE9 in Quirks Mode:

[image]

Also, for the sake of completeness:

[image]

The website is made of many iframes, and a new requirement arose:
I need to create a new iFrame, in which bootstrap will be used, and I need to render the content of this frame in **Internet Explorer 9 Standards** (i.e. Disable the Quirks Mode only in this iframe and render as usual).

I've tried putting

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Inside the iframe, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML5 doctype with an XML declaration in the markup linked to the `<iframe src="..."></iframe>` URL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en">
<!--...-->
</html>
```

> Thus, when XML content is hosted inside an IFRAME, a tree view will not automatically be generated by default. However, when the browser is running in Compatibility View, IE tries to more closely emulate the behavior of previous releases, which is why the tree view is still displayed under these circumstances.

OR XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="html5.xml"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" version="" indent="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
      These<br/>words<br/>are<br/>seperated<br/>by<br/>BRs
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**References**

- [XML is rendered as HTML when loaded into an IFRAME via iFrame.src = url](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/799821/xml-is-rendered-as-html-when-loaded-into-an-iframe-via-iframe-src-url)